# Simplish Flask methodview decorator

Tags: python, decorator, flask

I'm working on a decorator that validates an api token, my first being to get the decorator in some minimal working order:

```
def check_token(view_method):
    @wraps(view_method)
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args['token']
        if token is None:
            abort(403)
        return view_method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_view
```

This sort of works, i.e. the view works if the token is provided, but if not gives a 400 Bad Request error. I want to send a 403 error, but am not aware enough to catch this yet.

What is wrong with this that it only return a 400 error? How do I improve this?

Comment: Probably because `token = request.args['token']` itself is throwing `KeyError` before it reaches to `abort(403)`?

Comment: I mean there is no key `token` in `request.args`. Try `request.args.get('token', None)` instead and see if that works.

Comment: That is what I did not know at this point I think, lets try that.

Comment: That works, so I'd checkmark it if you did an answer below. request is a Werkzeug MultiDict, and with that I need to refine my understanding of that and python in general, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.args` is a `MultiDict` and it raises if a key is requested which is not there in dict. Here `request.args['token']` raises before it reaches to `abort(403)`. Few solutions are:

```
## If a 2nd optional argument is provided to dict.get then
## it does not raise if key is not found. Instead returns
## the 2nd argument passed as default.

token = request.args.get('token', None)
    if not token:
        ## Error handling
```

Or:

```
if 'token' not in request.args or not request.args['token']
    ## Error handling
```